# SELECT * FROM INNER JOIN - SELECT FROM TWO TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

```
TABLES
***************************************
| events           | attendance       |
***************************************
| event-id         | atd-id           |
| event-name       | event-id         |
| event-date-time  | user-id          |
| event-address    | guests           |
|                  |                  |
***************************************
```

event-date-time is (datetime) format.

I am trying to get all events that a user will attend, 
and order them by date and time.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM events, attendance 
WHERE `attendance.event-id` = `events.event-id` 
AND `attendance.user-id` = ".$user-id." ORDER BY `event-date-time` DESC";
```

DISPLAY ROWS:

- event-name, event-address, event-date-time
- event-name, event-address, event-date-time
- event-name, event-address, event-date-time
- event-name, event-address, event-date-time
- ...

I also tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `events` e
INNER JOIN `attendance` a ON a.event-id = e.event-id
ORDER BY `event-date-time` DESC
WHERE a.user-id = ".$user_id;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes after `WHERE`.  You should also learn to use parameters.

Comment: what is the error after fixing the order by clause.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Comment: See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

```
$sql = "SELECT e.*, a.atd-id, a.user-id, a.guests FROM `events` e
  LEFT JOIN `attendance` a ON a.event-id = e.event-id
  WHERE a.user-id = ".$user_id."
  ORDER BY `event-date-time` DESC;
```

`INNER JOIN` get records that are common on both tables.

`LEFT JOIN` get records from another table with referential identity.

On your case, you are referencing your table to another table based on referenced key `event-id` so left join must be used. Also, the `WHERE` clause must be placed before `Order By`.

If you're displaying parameters, still use the alias you have declared on each table of your query hence, specify the names.

Comment: i get #1054 - Unknown column 'a.atd-id' in 'field list'

Comment: So your attendance doesn't have `atd-id` column? Use `*` and see,

Comment: it does, is it because i am using a (-) instead or underscore (_)? i tried `atd-id` inside quotes

Comment: alter the names of your columns, changing (-) to (_).

Comment: `SELECT e.*, a.atd_id, a.user_id, a.guests FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.event_id = e.event_id
  WHERE a.user_id = 1
  ORDER BY event_date_time DESC;` Works

Comment: @RedDog & jned29 Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". This has that. PS "get records from another table with referential identity" is unclear & if it were clarified it would give only one use for LEFT JOIN. Learn what it calculates from inputs.

Comment: @RedDog You may consider marking check my answer if I have answered your questions correctly. thanks